# Redirect URL ending with dot

Tags: redirects, url, iis

I submitted my site's URL to my workplace's printed newsletter and when I get the printed version, they added a dot to the end of it. Some people will realize that the period is not a part of the URL but others will not. Is there an easy way to redirect from `http://example.com/home.` to `http://example.com/home`?

I have a IIS 7.0 shared hosting with GoDaddy. This means I have access to the box only through their interface so some options might be limited.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you had delivered your address as `http://example.com.` you'd be out of luck. Including a path or just the trailing slash (`http://example.com/.`) allows all of this to happen. Furthermore, if there was no path, there would be no need to configure anything.

Comment: This depends on the web server and configuration, which is IIS 7.0 on Windows in this case (periods aren't treated the same way as Linux/Unix). RFC1738 doesn't disallow periods in URL's either, see this for more on that: [Can . (period) be part of the path part of an URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7555553/can-period-be-part-of-the-path-part-of-an-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GoDaddy's Windows shared hosting accounts with IIS 7.0 support the [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5443/microsoft-url-rewrite-module), which provides URL redirect functionality similar to Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module, that the previous answer references.

To use this module, you would either modify or create a [web.config](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config) file, located in your root directory and then restart the IIS service.

I'm unable to test this, but that might look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect dot to domain " stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com/home.$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/home/{R:0}”
redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The lines to modify for your domain (and possibly the patterns too) are:

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com/home.$" />

<action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/home/{R:0}”
```

For more on pattern matching, see:  [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference: Rule Pattern](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Rule_Pattern)

Lastly, if this proves difficult for you and you're not dependent on using Windows for your web hosting account, you can simply switch to Linux web hosting with GoDaddy instead - see this for more:  [GoDaddy Support: Switching Your Hosting Account Operating System](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1285/switching-your-hosting-account-operating-system)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.comt$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^home\.$ "http\:\/\/example\/home" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's assuming they are using Apache. If they are on windows I would assume IIS.

Comment: It is IIS 7.0, with shared hosting you don't have access to the full machine unfortunately so that might also limit what I can do