# IIS 7 URL Rewrite Rule using query string variable

Tags: url-rewriting, iis7, query-string

Trying to create a URL Rewrite rule for IIS 7.5 to read the query string parameter and redirect requests to a new URL structure - for example:

`http://www.example.com/people/profile.aspx?dw`

to a new more SEO friendly URL at:

`http://www.example.com/our-people/profiles/dw`

Any good examples or guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make sure you have the [Microsoft URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference) installed, and create a rule template as covered step-by-step here:

[IIS.net - User Friendly URL - rule template](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/user-friendly-url-rule-template)

The other way to do this is edit your web.config file, as covered [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50312/redirect-url-ending-with-dot/50314#50314) (substituting your URL's under "The lines to modify...").

Comment: I had to tweak the resulting rules from the User Friendly URL templates results as the URL paths are slightly different, but this did the trick.

Comment: Great - glad it helped :-)