# www.example.com showing a 404 error while example.com is working when set up through cPanel

Tags: wordpress, dns, subdomain, iis

I set up a recent (Wordpress) project on Microsoft Azure with a domain from 123-reg. When I set up the DNS servers I am getting `example.com` is working to the site, but `www.example.com` isn't and is showing a `404` error.

If possible I would love to set up the DNS to allow either `www.example.com` or `example.com` to work. Even better if both can work!

I have worked with domains before mainly through cPanel which has great options that normally work for me, while doing it straight from the Domain service isn't showing any possible results.

Answer (score 3):

> **When I set up the DNS servers I am getting example.com is working to the site, but www.example.com isn't and is showing a 404 error.**

Since you're receiving a [404 error code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) from a server, that likely means your DNS is configured properly, but your web server is not redirecting to the same content that your *non-www* (root domain) is returning.

Assuming that your DNS is being managed by the domain registrar [123-reg](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/), you can verify that the DNS for *www* URLs is pointed to the same IP address that the *non-www* is pointed to via an `A record`, as pictured [here](http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains/Web-Forwarding/how-do-i-set-up-my-dns-for-web-forwarding-2526/).

Then if *non-www* URLs are the preferred ones you've been using or would like to use, you should do a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) in your web server from:   *wwww*  ->  *non-www*.

Lastly, it might be a good idea to tell Google which URL is preferred (i.e., the *non-www* one). See this for more:  [Preferred domain (www or non-www)](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231)

Comment: How could I for example get www.example.com working only. I'd love example.com to work as well but mainly want the www subdomain to work on the site.

Comment: You would just redirect _www_ to _non-www_, which is working, and both will return the same content then. Microsoft Azure would likely use IIS, so [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52144/naked-domain-to-www-redirect-in-windows-server-2008/52178#52178) might help, but I'd suggest checking the docs for Azure on how to do 301 redirects.

Comment: After some more digging around, it seems that 301 redirects in Azure are done with `web.config`. Using my answer [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50312/redirect-url-ending-with-dot/50314#50314), you might change the lines to modify to  `pattern="^www.$" />` and remove `home/` from `url=`

Comment: Perhaps even simpler for you might be to remove the `A record` for `www` and instead create a `CNAME` for `www` pointed to `example.com` as pictured in the second part of Example 2 [here](http://help.dnsmadeeasy.com/record-entry/cname/).

Answer (score 0):

To ad on Dan's answer: you should put this piece of code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: The OP is hosted on [Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/) which uses IIS (I'm going to add that tag). But that would be a helpful addition to someone using Apache.